# WiFi Failing and Keychain crashing

Tags: macos, wifi, keychain

I have a Macbook Pro 13 from about a year ago running OSX Lion.
Whenever I connect to my school's WiFi, I can't seem to get to the WiFi Login page
I was told the problem was probably in Keychain Access, but it crashes as soon as I try to open it whenever this is happening.
Using Safari or Chrome, I can't seem to get to any websites, it just hangs or gives me a page load error.
Firefox works though without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine had a similar problem. After trying the usual fixes (restarting, removing wi-fi networks, removing wi-fi network interface, resetting PRAM and SMC, deleting login keychain from ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain), I was able to solve the Keychain Access crashing (and wi-fi issues) using a solution from here: http://www.unsanity.org/archives/security/love_tropicana.php

In short, remove the wi-fi network (from System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Preferred Networks), then open Terminal and type in these two lines:

```
$ sudo mv /var/db/CodeEquivalenceDatabase
$ /var/db/CodeEquivalenceDatabase.old
```

(For more information, read the page I linked to above.)

Then restart, and see if Keychain Access opens - it did for me. You can then delete any passwords or certificates related to your school's wi-fi. Then try connecting to the network again.

Comment: That terminal command should be one long line, not two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your keychain is unlocked before removing entries.

[image]